# How to call ansible-playbook usnig static and dynamic inventory in different directories?

Tags: ansible

How do I use `ansible-playbook` with two inventories (static & dynamic) in different directories? The dynamic-inventory is a script which takes input as environment, e.g `dynamic-script -env my_env`

What I want to accomplish is something like this:

```
ansible-playbook -i static-inventory -i dynamic-inventory -env my_env playbook.yml
```

However only the first inventory is read.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put both inventory files in the same parent-directory and reference the directory as the ansible inventory. And check it with:

```
ansible-inventory -i parent-directoy
```

Comment: I do not have the possiblity to do so.. I'm aware of this solution

Comment: you should tell us, what else solutions you are aware of. It makes no sence to tell you the next solution and you answer again, i am aware of this solution, but it is not possible. And why it is not possible? Do you have more background informations?

Comment: I'll approve you solution. Though it's not been implemented. Thank you!